# get an array of elements from findElement(By.className())

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a script in node.js for selenium that will go to a page and grab the innerhtml of a certain css class and store them in an array.

```
var element = driver.findElement(By.className("hll"));
element.getInnerHtml().then(html){
    //returns 1 of the elements html where I want multiples
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Could you please clarify what your question is? If it's how to find multiple elements, begin with the plural [`.findElements()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html#findElements).

Comment: I just started learning selenium last night so apologies. If I run: var element = driver.findElements(By.className("hll")); how do I get the innerhtml of each index

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To retrieve the html of multiple elements, you can use [`driver.findElements()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html#findElements) to find all matches elements. This will provider a `Promise` that resolves with the elements in an `Array`.

```
var pendingElements = driver.findElements(By.className('h11'))

pendingElements.then(function (elements) {
    // ...
});
```

You'll need to iterate over the collection and request each element's HTML. You can use the `Array`'s [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a collection of promises from `getInnerHtml()`:

```
var pendingHtml = elements.map(function (elem) {
    return elem.getInnerHtml();
});
```

To wait for them to be resolved, you can pass the collection to [`promise.all()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/namespace_webdriver_promise.html#all).

```
promise.all(pendingHtml).then(function (allHtml) {
    // ...
});
```

Note, you'll need a reference to Selenium's `promise` for that.

```
var promise = require('selenium-webdriver').promise;
```

---

Combined:

```
// ...

var promise = require('selenium-webdriver').promise;

var pendingElements = driver.findElements(By.className('h11'))

pendingElements.then(function (elements) {
    var pendingHtml = elements.map(function (elem) {
        return elem.getInnerHtml();
    });

    promise.all(pendingHtml).then(function (allHtml) {
        // `allHtml` will be an `Array` of strings
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! This totally worked but I had to change the selector to an xpath of this: xpath("//*[@class='hll']")

Comment: Is it possible to convert div/table into json format with above code?