# Selenium how to get the elements who doesn't have a name or id

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, testing

i want to find the two inputs using selenium using findElement by css
i want to fill in the two inputs, i was only able to find one input with "input[type='text']" and im not sure how to get the other one
please check my html

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/tasks">Todo List</a
    ><button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/tasks">Tâches</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Déconnexion</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container mt-5"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Liste des tâches</h2>
  <div class="alert alert-info">Aucune tâche n'a encore été créée.</div>
  <hr />
  <h2>Créer une nouvelle tâche</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <label>Nom de la tâche</label
      ><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label>Description de la tâche en une ligne</label
      ><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <br /><button class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter la tâche</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use XPath, and to find it easily open Inspect Element, right click on input, click on Copy XPath,
or you can get all matching elements and select it from the list, like
`findElements("input[type='text']")[0]`
`findElements("input[type='text']")[1]`

Comment: both didn't work for i get "Invalid locator"
is this code for JS?
the xPath didn't work i get this error NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/input

Comment: what is your code in? can you try to print `findElements("input[type='text']")` and see what's there? and showing your original command that works for one input might be helpful

Comment: NodeJS, this is my command that is only finding the first input 
driver.findElement(By.css("input[type='text']")).sendKeys("test");

Comment: oh I see, so I think you can use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098156/get-an-array-of-elements-from-findelementby-classname - it seems findElements returns a promise in nodejs

Comment: i just needed to copy the correct Xpath, it's working as a charm thanks

Answer (score 1):

By xpath, for example in Firefox

Right click on page -> Select (Inspect Element), pick an element from the page, then right click on highlighted html -> Copy -> Xpath

Check
https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/complete-guide-for-using-xpath-in-selenium-with-examples/

Comment: i did copy Xpath and used it as bellow 
await driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("test");
but i got this error 
(node:26840) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/input

Comment: Wait for an element to appear https://www.browserstack.com/guide/wait-commands-in-selenium-webdriver in wait explicitly.

Comment: already using await

Answer (score 0):

If you found the first input element, you can simply do the same you did to find it but use `find_elements()` instead of `find_element()`.
It will return a list with the two inputs.